# how can we use uglify for multiple file outputs

Tags: npm, uglifyjs, grunt-contrib-uglify

Is it possible to compile each file separeately in uglify js instaed of uglifying in to one single file.

uglifyjs assets/src/js/ *js  -o assets/dist/js/ *.min.js -c

like this

Answer (score 0):

```
module.exports = function(grunt) {

    grunt.config.set('uglify', {
        options: {
            mangle: false,
            sourceMap: false,
            screwIE8: true,
            compress: {
                unused: false,
                drop_console: true
            }
        },

    uglifyjsfiles:{
            files: grunt.file.expandMapping(['.tmp/public/js/app/**/*.js'], '', {
                rename: function(destBase, destPath) {
                    return destBase+destPath.replace('.js', '.min.js');
                }
            })
    },

 });

    grunt.loadNpmTasks('grunt-contrib-uglify');
};
```

> Now run grunt uglify:uglifyjsfiles